# Grabbing information between key words javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have an app that is being fed HTML into a variable. I need to find the url for the first image file in the HTML (if there is a link at all). This is what I have right now:

```
var media = row.content.substring(row.content.indexOf('<img src="') + 1, row.content.indexOf('"'));
```

However, this is not grabbing the correct information. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide some input example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd `indexOf` is going to return, at the very least, the `"` from `<img src="`, possibly an earlier one.  Try:

```
var ix,
   media = row.content.substring(
      ix = row.content.indexOf('<img src="') + 1, row.content.indexOf('"', ix+10)
   );
```

which will ensure that it finds the first quote *after* the one in the img src.

A better way to do this is with a regex:

```
var media = (row.content.match(/<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)/) || 0)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

row.content.indexOf('"') is returning the position of first double quote which is right after src=